# Model as dependency property used within different threads

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I do have the following szenario. I created a WPF C# project that follows the MVVM pattern. Furthermore I developed a user control that is some kind of a image drawer. Now I create a Model within the viewmodel and share it with the usercontrol as dependency property. This is done like this:

User control:

```
public DXModel Model
    {
        get { return (DXModel)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(DXModel), typeof(DXControl),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(null, OnChanged));

    static void OnChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as DXControl).OnChanged();
    }

    void OnChanged()
    {
        if (Model != null)
            Model.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Model_Changed);  // comes from the ui thread...comes only when init model...ok
        textTitle.Text = Model.Title;
        internalModel = (DXModel)Model;
    }

    void Model_Changed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!receiveTimer.Enabled)
        {
            receiveTimer.Interval = receiveDelay;
            receiveTimer.Start();
            refreshTimer.Start();
        }
    }
```

So I also get the event when the Model was changed in the viewmodel and I then perform the drawing. Basically I have a list of points which I completely overwrite within the viewmodel several times per second:

ViewModel:

```
dxModel1.Series[0].Points = list1;
```

In the User control the points are redrawn also several times per second. To do so, I have to iterate through the points first:

User control:

```
int length = internalModel.Series[i].Points.Count-1;
float lastX = internalModel.Series[i].Points[0].X;
for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
    {
      float x = ((float)targetImage.Width - 0) / (internalModel.Axes[0].Max - internalModel.Axes[0].Min) * (internalModel.Series[i].Points[j].X- lastX - internalModel.Axes[0].Min);
      float y = (0 - (float)targetImage.Height) / (internalModel.Axes[1].Max - internalModel.Axes[1].Min) * (internalModel.Series[i].Points[j].Y - internalModel.Axes[1].Min) + (float)targetImage.Height;
      tmpPoints.Add(new SharpDX.Vector2(x, y));
    }
```

What is important, the Model is changed in a worker thread within the viewmodel. The user control is living in the ui thread. The problem I have is that this iteration through the points gives me an exception from time to time. I guess, this is because The points are overwritten in the worker thread at the same time it iterates through the points.

I tried to lock the internalModel in the usercontrol and the dxModel1 within the viewmodel but that did not help me.

Am I right with my approach why it fails and if so, how could I overcome this issue?

Comment: Dependency properties are unnecessary for MVVM. They are very useful if you're creating *custom controls*, though. Just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: You _will_ need locks to get this working properly. Locking the internal model doesn't sound like a bad idea... try again, isolete the problem and update your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are working with .net4.5, I think by using async-await in your method should take care of this issue. some link I came across with: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/c/1514-async-await-and-the-ui-problem.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem as you *didn't tell us the `Exception` details*, but if you just want to ensure that your code runs on the UI thread, you can do something like this:

```
RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate()
{
    int length = internalModel.Series[i].Points.Count-1;
    float lastX = internalModel.Series[i].Points[0].X;
    for (int j = 0; j <= length; j++)
    {
        float x = ((float)targetImage.Width - 0) / (internalModel.Axes[0].Max - internalModel.Axes[0].Min) * (internalModel.Series[i].Points[j].X- lastX - internalModel.Axes[0].Min);
        float y = (0 - (float)targetImage.Height) / (internalModel.Axes[1].Max - internalModel.Axes[1].Min) * (internalModel.Series[i].Points[j].Y - internalModel.Axes[1].Min) + (float)targetImage.Height;
        tmpPoints.Add(new SharpDX.Vector2(x, y));
    }
});

...

public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```